# Zabbix userparameter with multiple values doesn't work

Tags: bash, freebsd, zabbix

I am trying to make Zabbix item workable on FreeBSD for gathering info from SQUID.

I have the next UserParameter:

```
UserParameter=data.sclient[*], printf "GET cache_object://localhost/purgeng/$2 HTTP/1.0\nAccept */*\n\n" | for i in $(echo "$1" | tr "," "\n" ); do nc -w 3 127.0.0.1 $i ; done | awk '/^[[:space:]]*$$
/ {getline;split($$0, a, / = /);print a[2]} END{if(!NR) print -2}'
```

But it works only with one port value, for example:

```
zabbix_get -s 192.168.1.7 -p 10050 -k data.sclient["1111",distributors/configured]
6
```

When I try with two port values:

```
zabbix_get -s 192.168.1.7 -p 10050 -k data.sclient["1111,2222",distributors/configured]
false
```

Could you please help me to make it work with multiple ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in incorrect setting of for loop.

I did:

```
UserParameter=data.sclient[*], for i in $(echo $1); do printf "GET cache_object://localhost/purgeng/$2 HTTP/1.0\nAccept */*\n\n" | nc -w 3 127.0.0.1 $i ; done | awk '/^[[:space:]]*$$/ {getline;split($$0, a, / = /);print a[2]} END{if(!NR) print -2}'

$ zabbix_get -s 192.168.1.7 -p 10050 -k data.sclient["1111 2222",distributors/connected]
3
3
```

Comment: You should probably keep in mind that you cannot use more than one returned value from an item in Zabbix itself. When you configure items in the frontend/server, they all can consume a single value only.

Comment: Hi, yes I already realized it. Could you please suggest an alternative way as workaround? The problem is that low level discovery rule reads ports from json array and I need to track each of those ports. Is it possible rather than create via discovery rule a separate item per each of ports ?

Comment: You must have separate items to receive different values - how would you distinguish them later otherwise? How the items are created is different from populating them, though. Creating can be handled with LLD, API etc. Populating can be handled with separate polling, zabbix_sender etc.